# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Online Accounts

Tags: facebook, accounts

I am new in Ubuntu, and try to setup my Facebook account on my desktop in order to online chat/messaging via my FB account, but when I click on Facebook on System Settings>Online Accounts it gives blank page and write that; You have to capacitate Ubuntu to access Facebook account. What should I do to give that capacitate ? And also I tried to use Facebook Messenger and Empathy and they just give me the blank page ,too.